# Using Model Builder to create folders

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

[image]

I'm currently running iterate rasters that scrubs through a bunch of subfolders based on counties. I currently have the output going to a new folder where they are all aggregated.

Using the create folder tool, is it possible to copy the parent folders (Counties) and place all of these iterated rasters into new folders based on the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seek can be achieved by using the Parse path tool along with inline variable substitution. The Parse path tool is a precondition to the Create Folder and its output is a precondition to the Copy Raster tool.

[image: Model]

The Top level folder is as:

[image: Top Level]

The model outputs:

[image: Results]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I was getting a little confused using the Parse Path tool and not sure how the precondition setting should function. This clarifies a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: One clarification, do the folder names matter? I noticed you have %New Folder% as well as %New Sub Folder%, not sure which convention to follow. Will experiment in the meantime...

Comment: No the variable name could be anything but clearly sensible naming helps you or others understand what you intend the variable should contain.